# Extract timestamp from filename and add it in new column(say,date) by using Pig

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig, cloudera, hortonworks-data-platform

I have a file with name `YYYYMMDD_claims_portal.csv`, I need only `YYYYMMDD` part and store this value in new column (say, date).

Earlier we have 3 columns: `Claim,User,ID`. Now I need to add one more column date having value as `YYYYMMDD` as per file.

Comment: I removed the *"it's urgent"* comment from the question. Please take a look at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/7605325

Answer (score 0):

**input__file__name**

---

#### Demo

bash

```
[]$ mkdir mytable
[]$ cat>mytable/20170918_claims_portal.csv
1
2
[]$ cat>mytable/20170919_claims_portal.csv
3
[]$ cat>mytable/20170920_claims_portal.csv
4
5
6
```

hive

```
create external table mytable (i int) stored as textfile
;
```

---

```
select  i
       ,regexp_extract(input__file__name,'(\\d{8})_claims_portal.csv',1) as dt 
       
from    mytable
;
```

---

```
+----+-----------+
| i  |    dt     |
+----+-----------+
| 4  | 20170920  |
| 5  | 20170920  |
| 6  | 20170920  |
| 3  | 20170919  |
| 1  | 20170918  |
| 2  | 20170918  |
+----+-----------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. I'm going to try this for sure..but could you please tell me what is input__file__name here, i mean is it table name from which we are deriving YYYYMMDD_claims_portal.csv file or something else.Thanks alot.

Comment: Hey..Thanks @Dudu ..got it..Its working for me..thanks.